# Whats an efficient way to stop these transparency overlaps in webgl?

Tags: webgl, transparency, overlap, isometric

I would like to make it so that these blocks are all drawn to one layer than that entire layer is made transparent. Or if there is a way I can use blend functions or alpha blending to do it that would be fine too. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What is your definition of efficient? Under what circumstances? What conditions?

Here's a few solutions. It's hard to tell if they fit without more details.

First let's repo the issue

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0, .5, 0, .5);
}
`;

// compile shaders, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// create buffers and upload vertex data
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);

render();
function render() {
  gl.clearColor(0, .4, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

  const halfHeight = 1;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const halfWidth = halfHeight * aspect;
  const projection = m4.ortho(
    -halfWidth, halfWidth, -halfHeight, halfWidth, 0.1, 20);

  const camera = m4.lookAt(
    [5, 2, 5],  // eye
    [0, -.5, 0],  // target
    [0, 1, 0],  // up
  );
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  const viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);

  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  for (let x = -1; x <= 1; ++x) {
    let mat = m4.translate(viewProjection, [x, 0, 0]);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      u_matrix: mat,
    });
    // calls drawArrays or drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Note the example above just clears the background to [0, .4, 0, 1] which is dark green. It then draws 3 cubes using [0, .5, 0, .5] which is full green (as in [0, 1, 0, 1]) except premultiplied by 50% alpha. Using premultiplied colors the blending is set to `gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` Face culling is on.

As for solutions off the top of my head looking at your picture you could

### Draw front to back with z-test on

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0, .5, 0, .5);
}
`;

// compile shaders, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// create buffers and upload vertex data
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);

render();
function render() {
  gl.clearColor(0, .4, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  
  gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

  const halfHeight = 1;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const halfWidth = halfHeight * aspect;
  const projection = m4.ortho(
    -halfWidth, halfWidth, -halfHeight, halfWidth, 0.1, 20);

  const camera = m4.lookAt(
    [5, 2, 5],  // eye
    [0, -.5, 0],  // target
    [0, 1, 0],  // up
  );
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  const viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  for (let x = 1; x >= -1; --x) {
    let mat = m4.translate(viewProjection, [x, 0, 0]);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      u_matrix: mat,
    });
    // calls drawArrays or drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Note the only changes to the top version are the addition of

```
 gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
```

And drawing in reverse order

```
 for (let x = 1; x >= -1; --x) {
```

I have no idea how your data is stored. Assuming it's a grid you'd have to write code to iterate over the grid in the correct order from the view of the camera.

### Your example only shows a green background so you could just draw opaque and multiply or mix by a color, the same color as your background.

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 u_backgroundColor;
uniform float u_mixAmount;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = mix(vec4(0, 1, 0, 1), u_backgroundColor, u_mixAmount);
}
`;

// compile shaders, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// create buffers and upload vertex data
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);

render();
function render() {
  gl.clearColor(0, .4, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

  const halfHeight = 1;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const halfWidth = halfHeight * aspect;
  const projection = m4.ortho(
    -halfWidth, halfWidth, -halfHeight, halfWidth, 0.1, 20);

  const camera = m4.lookAt(
    [5, 2, 5],  // eye
    [0, -.5, 0],  // target
    [0, 1, 0],  // up
  );
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  const viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  for (let x = 1; x >= -1; --x) {
    let mat = m4.translate(viewProjection, [x, 0, 0]);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      u_matrix: mat,
      u_backgroundColor: [0, 0.4, 0, 1],
      u_mixAmount: 0.5,
    });
    // calls drawArrays or drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

The solution above changes the fragment shader to

```
uniform vec4 u_backgroundColor;
uniform float u_mixAmount;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = mix(vec4(0, 1, 0, 1), u_backgroundColor, u_mixAmount);
}
```

Where `vec4(0, 1, 0, 1)` is the cube's green color. We then set `u_backgroundColor` to match the background color of 0, .4, 0, 1 and set `u_mixAmount` to .5 (50%)

This solution might sound dumb but it's common to want to fade to a background color which is basically how fog works. You don't actually make things more transparent in the distance you just draw with the fog color.

### draw all the tiles without transparency into another texture, then draw that texture with transparency

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl', {alpha: false});
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
}
`;

const mixVs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
  v_texcoord = texcoord;
}
`;

const mixFs = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_tex;
uniform float u_alpha;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_tex, v_texcoord) * u_alpha;
}
`;

// compile shaders, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
const mixProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [mixVs, mixFs]);

// create buffers and upload vertex data
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);
const xyQuadBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(gl);

// create framebuffer with RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture
// and depth buffer renderbuffer that matches the size 
// of the canvas
const fbi = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(gl);

render();

function render() {
  renderTiles();
  renderScene();
}

function renderScene() {
  // bind canvas and set viewport
  twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(gl, null);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0.4, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  gl.useProgram(mixProgramInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, mixProgramInfo, xyQuadBufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(mixProgramInfo, {
    u_matrix: m4.identity(),
    u_tex: fbi.attachments[0],  // the texture
    u_alpha: .5,
  });
  // calls drawArrays or drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, xyQuadBufferInfo);
}

function renderTiles() {
  // bind framebuffer and set viewport
  twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(gl, fbi);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.disable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

  const halfHeight = 1;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const halfWidth = halfHeight * aspect;
  const projection = m4.ortho(
    -halfWidth, halfWidth, -halfHeight, halfWidth, 0.1, 20);

  const camera = m4.lookAt(
    [5, 2, 5],  // eye
    [0, -.5, 0],  // target
    [0, 1, 0],  // up
  );
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  const viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);
  
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  for (let x = 1; x >= -1; --x) {
    let mat = m4.translate(viewProjection, [x, 0, 0]);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      u_matrix: mat,
      u_backgroundColor: [0, 0.4, 0, 1],
      u_mixAmount: 0.5,
    });
    // calls drawArrays or drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

The change above creates an RGBA texture and a depth renderbuffer the same size as the canvas and attaches them to a framebuffer. It then renders the tiles into that texture opaquely. Then it renders the texture over the canvas with 50% alpha. Note that the canvas itself is set to `{alpha: false}` so that the canvas doesn't blend with the elements behind it.

### Generate new geometry that doesn't have the hidden surfaces

The problem is your drawing 3 cubes and the edges between them. A Minecraft like solution would probably generate new geometry that didn't have the inner edges. It would be pretty easy to walk a grid of tiles and decide whether or not to add that edge of the cube based on if there is a neighbor or not.

In Minecraft they only have to generate new geometry when blocks are added or removed and with some creative coding that might involve only modifying a few vertices rather than regenerating the entire mesh. They also probably generate in a gird like very 64x64x64 area.